# Read multiple files with SparkSession in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark 1.6 to read multiple files, I have used:

```
JavaSparkContext ctx;
ctx.textFile(filePaths);
```

With `filePaths` is the directory to files. For example we have:
`/home/user/folderA/0.log,/home/user/folderB/0.log`. Each path separates by comma character.

But, when I upgrade to Spark 2.0. Method

```
SparkSession sparkSession;
sparkSession.read().textFile(filePaths);
```

doesn't work. The code throws exception: `Path does not exist:`

Question: Is there any solution to read multiple files, from multiple paths in Spark 2.0 just like Spark 1.6?

**Edit:** I try to call the method like Spark 1.6 using:

```
sparkSession.sparkContext().textFile(filePaths, 1).toJavaRDD();
```

The problem will solved. But, Is there have another solution?

Comment: Thank @mtoto. Method `wholeTextFiles` doesn't belong to `SparkSession` class. If we try to create `sparkContext` and then call `textFile(filePaths)` like Spark 1.6. The problem will solve. But, I want to solve this problem using Spark 2.0, not like Spark 1.6. :D

Comment: it maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651742/dataset-api-analog-of-javasparkcontext-wholetextfiles

Comment: sparkContext is accessible from sparkSession like you have tried: spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles