# Dataset-API analog of JavaSparkContext.wholeTextFiles

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

We can call `JavaSparkContext.wholeTextFiles` and get `JavaPairRDD<String, String>`, where first String is file name and second String is whole file contents. Is there similar method in Dataset API, or all I can do is to load files into `JavaPairRDD` and then convert to Dataset (which is working, but I'm looking for non-RDD solution).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Dataset API then you can use `spark.read.text("path/to/files/")`. Please check [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#text(java.lang.String...)) for API details. Please note that using `text()` method returns Dataframe in which "**Each line in the text files is a new row in the resulting DataFrame**". So `text()` method will provide file content. In order to get the file name you will have to use `input_file_name()` function.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name;
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().text("c:\\temp").withColumnRenamed("value", "content").withColumn("fileName", input_file_name());
ds.show(false);
```

If you want to concatenate rows from same file so it will be like whole file content, you would need to use `groupBy` function on fileName column with `concat_ws` and `collect_list` functions.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list;
ds = ds.groupBy(col("fileName")).agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(ds.col("content"))).as("content"));
ds.show(false);
```

Comment: abaghel, thank you! One more question - how do we do in `Dataset` what can be done with `JavaRDD.map`? For example, in `JavaRDD` I can filter member of the array which is the element of `JavaRDD` by some set/map which is not the part of `JavaRDD`. Or I can replace a field of JavaPairRDD with value foind in map. In general, in `map/mapToPair` methods I can do whatever, involving any object I have in my application. `Dataset` seems to be limited to SQL-like APIs.

Comment: There are map and filter functions in Dataset as well. Please check the API at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html. Please post a separate question with details for your issue with Dataset.